# Single word for "little one can do"

Tags: single-word-requests

The world is ending in 5 seconds. You have 3 seconds to press the "Prevent Destruction Button" but this button is 100 light years away, and probably doesn't even exist. You could say there is little you can do in this situation.

What word is a good substitute for "little one can do" in a context such as the above (which I just made up as an example)

Comment: "little one can do" is ambiguous. Do you really mean 'little one(a small boy or so) can do'- a positive idea, or 'there is little one can do'-there is nothing one can do-a negative idea?

Comment: This may be an exercise in ***futility***.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 'vain'.
Such as: I stared out at the fires, knowing any attempt to reach the button would be in vain.
Or futile, which I think is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that any action is **futile**, or that you are **impotent**, or that you are **powerless** to prevent the disaster.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where there is ''little/nothing one can do'' could possibly be termed as **an [insurmountable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insurmountable) situation.**
**Insurmountable:**

> :of a problem, difficulty, etc. 
>  
>   : impossible to solve or get control of 
>  
>   : impossible to overcome

>**So your situation is insurmountable.**

You can also say [insuperable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insuperable) , it's synonym.

One word substitute for ''little one can do'' doesn't come to my mind but if you are trapped in seemingly 'insurmountable' situation, obviously there is ''little you can do'':)